# how to iterate and save data in another list in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

This is my data::

0 = {DailyGraphData@12509} "DailyGraphData(id=122, appName=GoRestApp, packageName=com.anil.gorestapp, totalAppTimeInForeground=162000, lastTimeUsed=2021-12-04 01:07:01, beginningTime=2021-12-04 01:04:19, endTime=2021-12-04 01:07:01, isChild=true, category=other)"

1 = {DailyGraphData@12510} "DailyGraphData(id=123, appName=Pixel Launcher, packageName=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher, totalAppTimeInForeground=18000, lastTimeUsed=2021-12-04 01:04:22, beginningTime=2021-12-04 01:04:20, endTime=2021-12-04 01:04:22, isChild=true, category=other)"

2 = {DailyGraphData@12511} "DailyGraphData(id=1, appName=Pixel Launcher, packageName=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher, totalAppTimeInForeground=14036000, lastTimeUsed=2021-12-04 02:02:57, beginningTime=2021-12-04 01:00:00, endTime=2021-12-04 02:00:00, isChild=false, category=other)"

3 = {DailyGraphData@12512} "DailyGraphData(id=4, appName=GoRestApp, packageName=com.anil.gorestapp, totalAppTimeInForeground=46406000, lastTimeUsed=2021-12-04 00:52:26, beginningTime=2021-12-04 00:50:55, endTime=2021-12-04 00:52:26, isChild=false, category=other)"

4 = {DailyGraphData@12514} "DailyGraphData(id=19, appName=Package installer, packageName=com.google.android.packageinstaller, totalAppTimeInForeground=18000, lastTimeUsed=2021-12-04 00:54:18, beginningTime=2021-12-04 00:54:17, endTime=2021-12-04 00:54:18, isChild=false, category=other)"

5 = {DailyGraphData@12515} "DailyGraphData(id=215, appName=Certificate Installer, packageName=com.android.certinstaller, totalAppTimeInForeground=14000, lastTimeUsed=2021-12-04 00:36:12, beginningTime=2021-12-04 00:36:05, endTime=2021-12-04 00:36:12, isChild=false, category=other)"

6 = {DailyGraphData@12516} "DailyGraphData(id=299, appName=Usage Stats, packageName=at.ciit.usagestats, totalAppTimeInForeground=7810000, lastTimeUsed=2021-12-04 04:05:59, beginningTime=2021-12-04 04:05:33, endTime=2021-12-04 04:05:59, isChild=false, category=other)"
I am saving this data in parentChildResult

```
 val parentChildResult :ArrayList<DailyGraphData>
```

I want to iterate this list and i want save this data in another child list data in such manner so that if isChild is true  then totalAppTimeInForeground should go to childUsageDuration and if !isChild then it should go parentUsageDuration and it should return Single item and should add in Single list

```
data class Monitor(
  
    var appName: String,
    var packageName: String,
    var category: String,
    var parentUsageDuration: Long? = 0L,
    var childUsageDuration: Long? = 0L
)
```

I am trying in this way

```
 var listOfMonitor: ArrayList<Monitor> = ArrayList()
            var parentTime: Long? = 0L
            var childTime: Long? = 0L
            for (item in value) {
                if (item.isChild){
                    childTime = item.totalAppTimeInForeground
                }
                else{
                    parentTime = item.totalAppTimeInForeground
                }
               listOfMonitor.add(Monitor(appName = item.appName,packageName = item.packageName,category= item.category,parentUsageDuration = parentTime,childUsageDuration = childTime))
            }
```

but i am unable to make this as group by app wise please help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've written in your question, you want to `group by app`.
Coincidental the Kotlin standard library contains a function called `groupBy` which sound quite fitting.

```kotlin
val listOfMonitor: List<Monitor> = parentChildResult
    .groupBy { it.appName }
    .map { (appName, appGraphData) ->
        val sampleGraphData = appGraphData.first()
        val (childDataPoints, parentDataPoints) = appGraphData.partition { it.isChild }

        Monitor(
            appName = appName,
            sampleGraphData.packageName,
            sampleGraphData.category,
            parentDataPoints.sumOf { it.totalAppTimeInForeground },
            childDataPoints.sumOf { it.totalAppTimeInForeground },
        )
    }

val arrayListOfMonitor: ArrayList<Monitor> = ArrayList(listOfMonitor)
```

The above first creates groups based on the apps name.
For each such group, the list of corresponding `DailyGraphData` objects is split in two, based on whether a data point is for a child or not.
Both `parentUsageDuration` and `childUsageDuration` then is the `sumOf` the `totalAppTimeInForeground` of the corresponding list items.

---

I based my answer on the following data.

```kotlin
data class DailyGraphData(
    val id: Int,
    val appName: String,
    val packageName: String,
    val totalAppTimeInForeground: Long,
    val lastTimeUsed: String,
    val beginningTime: String,
    val endTime: String,
    val isChild: Boolean,
    val category: String,
)

val parentChildResult = listOf(
    DailyGraphData(
        id = 122,
        appName = "GoRestApp",
        packageName = "com.anil.gorestapp",
        totalAppTimeInForeground = 162000,
        lastTimeUsed = "2021-12-04 01:07:01",
        beginningTime = "2021-12-04 01:04:19",
        endTime = "2021-12-04 01:07:01",
        isChild = true,
        category = "other"
    ),
    DailyGraphData(
        id = 123,
        appName = "Pixel Launcher",
        packageName = "com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher",
        totalAppTimeInForeground = 18000,
        lastTimeUsed = "2021-12-04 01:04:22",
        beginningTime = "2021-12-04 01:04:20",
        endTime = "2021-12-04 01:04:22",
        isChild = true,
        category = "other"
    ),
    DailyGraphData(
        id = 1,
        appName = "Pixel Launcher",
        packageName = "com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher",
        totalAppTimeInForeground = 14036000,
        lastTimeUsed = "2021-12-04 02:02:57",
        beginningTime = "2021-12-04 01:00:00",
        endTime = "2021-12-04 02:00:00",
        isChild = false,
        category = "other"
    ),
    DailyGraphData(
        id = 4,
        appName = "GoRestApp",
        packageName = "com.anil.gorestapp",
        totalAppTimeInForeground = 46406000,
        lastTimeUsed = "2021-12-04 00:52:26",
        beginningTime = "2021-12-04 00:50:55",
        endTime = "2021-12-04 00:52:26",
        isChild = false,
        category = "other"
    ),
    DailyGraphData(
        id = 19,
        appName = "Package installer",
        packageName = "com.google.android.packageinstaller",
        totalAppTimeInForeground = 18000,
        lastTimeUsed = "2021-12-04 00:54:18",
        beginningTime = "2021-12-04 00:54:17",
        endTime = "2021-12-04 00:54:18",
        isChild = false,
        category = "other"
    ),
    DailyGraphData(
        id = 215,
        appName = "Certificate Installer",
        packageName = "com.android.certinstaller",
        totalAppTimeInForeground = 14000,
        lastTimeUsed = "2021-12-04 00:36:12",
        beginningTime = "2021-12-04 00:36:05",
        endTime = "2021-12-04 00:36:12",
        isChild = false,
        category = "other"
    ),
    DailyGraphData(
        id = 299,
        appName = "Usage Stats",
        packageName = "at.ciit.usagestats",
        totalAppTimeInForeground = 7810000,
        lastTimeUsed = "2021-12-04 04:05:59",
        beginningTime = "2021-12-04 04:05:33",
        endTime = "2021-12-04 04:05:59",
        isChild = false,
        category = "other"
    ),
)
```

Comment: thanks @Endzeit let me try this logic

Comment: i tried this  app is grouping that is correct but i want to set if(!isChild)parentUsageDuration = totalAppTimeInForeground and if(isChild)childUsageDuration = totalAppTimeInForeground
as per your answer i am getting 0 while for  GoRestApp APp parentUsageDuration = 162000 and for childUsageDuration =46406000   i.e it should be 
0 = {Monitor@11650} "Monitor(appName=GoRestApp, packageName=com.anil.gorestapp, category=other, lastTimeUsed=46406000, totalAppTimeInForeground=162000, lastTotalTimeInForeground=0, parentUsageDuration=162000, childUsageDuration=46406000)"

Comment: Wait let me check i think i have set value properly

Comment: The `Monitor` class provided in your question did not contain any of the properties `lastTimeUsed`, `totalAppTimeInForeground` and `lastTotalTimeInForeground`.

Comment: here problem is you are returning List<Monitor> while i wanted ArrayList<Monitor> can we convert it to ArrayList<Monitor>?

Comment: Sure, I adjusted my answer. Are you certain you need an `ArrayList` though? Most often than not, a more generic `List` would suffice.